# Tree JavaScript code not working with Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I need help for fixing up the bug on my JavaScript program. This program perfectly works fine on Google chrome and firefox, but the code dont works with internet explorer 8, giving a strange error mentioned below. Please someone give me a solution for my program. The fiddle link is given below

Error is:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
File: treelist.js, Line: 12, Column: 13
```

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliparvez20/Ek2xS/52/)

---

```
var dataSource = {
            "Watch": {
                "Titan": {},
                "parent": {
                    "leaf1": {},
                    "leaf2": {}
                },
            }
        },
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = e.currentTarget.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    e.currentTarget.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    e.currentTarget.className = e.currentTarget.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas at the end of the members declaration are not supported in IE8.

Try to remove them, and it should work:

```
 dataSource = {
        "Watch": {
            "Titan": {},
            "parent": {
                "leaf1": {},
                "leaf2": {}
            }, <-- remove this
        }
```

Apart from this, you are refering to "Object.keys" which is not supported in IE8:

```
  if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length)
```

You can solve it by adding this:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
   Object.keys = function(obj) {
      var keys = [];

      for (var i in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            keys.push(i);
         }
      }  

      return keys;
   };
}
```

Comment: @user3237973 Try now! I forgot to mention the Object.keys problem in IE8 ... (edited)

Comment: can u give me a live fiddle... i cant understand you

Answer (score 0):

Schema is too complicated  and a bit strange for interpretation of tree structures in JS.

IF you have chance to re design it  to have something like this :

```
var dataSource = {
            name : "Watch",
            nodes : [
                {
                 name : "Titan",
                 nodes: [],
                },
                {
                 name : "parent",
                 node : [
                     {
                      name : "leaf1",
                      nodes : []
                     },
                      {
                      name : "leaf2",
                      nodes : []
                      }
                 ]
                },
            ]
        };
```

your code can be hugely reduced, and will work fine without annoying cross-browser stuff without hacks.

Comment: I will try to follow you way..Thank you